# Using Git when contribution using 2 repository

Tags: git, github

i am just wondering what is the best way to commit when we have 2 repository (one main repository and one cloned repository)

Assuming... There is a Project1(Project 1 Repository) in User1 Github account

i am cloning and make it RajProject1 from User1:Project1

Now how can i use my repository and User1:project1 repository how can i commit to both repository?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways:
Commit & push to your own repository, then make a pull request so that your changes can be included in the original repo. This is how collaboration on GitHub normally works.

Otherwise, if you have push access to the original repo, you can add both your repo and the original repo as remote (git remote add  ) to your local copy and after that you can push the changes to both repos.

Comment: Once I commit and push to my repository do i need to use git checkout to original repository and then pull from my repository and then send an pull request to original... ?

Comment: No. Once you have pushed to your remote repository, you can simply use the UI on github to create a pull-request.